How do I sum a series or rows by a formula that considers two columns in excel
Im after a formula that can calulate the sum of an operation between two columns without creating another column.
e.g. Given the below table



Column Value
Column Percent 1
Column Percent 2




100
50%
80%


200
25%
60%



I want a formula that calculates the sum of the Value Column * the percentage. e.g.
The total for

Column Percent 1: would be 50 (100*.5) + 50 (200*.25) = 100
Column Percent 2: Would be 80 (100 *. 8) + 120 (200 * .6) = 200


Try using SUMPRODUCT() or SUM() function (if using MS365)


• Column Percent 1:
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A3,B2:B3)


• Column Percent 2:
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A3,C2:C3)


